# How to query Customer name from transaction table based on master table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to query customer name from master table based on three column of transaction table.

#### Other details

I have two tables in access 2010 (imported from dbf files):

**MASTER table**

```
+------------+-----------------+
| Field      | Sample data     |
+------------+-----------------+
| type       | G or S or C     |
| MASTERcode | 10 or 20 or 30  |
| SUBcode    | A1 or b1 or c1  |
|Customername|   xyz ind       |  
| Address    |    data         |
| OTHERS     | OTHER DATA      |
+------------+-----------------+
```

customer name will have three field related to it type | master code | sucode

**TRANSACTION table**

```
+------------+-----------------+
| Field      | Sample data     |
+------------+-----------------+
| type       | G or S or C     |
| MASTERcode | 10 or 20 or 30  |
| SUBcode    | A1 or b1 or c1  |
| TRN DATE   | DATE            |  
| TRN AMOUNT | AMOUNT          |
| OTHERS     | OTHER DATE      |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Transaction table has three filed type | mastercode | subcode with other data.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what is your desired result, but you can do a simple `JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT T.*,              --list of the columns from the Transaction table
       M.Customername
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE AS T
INNER JOIN MASTER_TABLE AS M
    ON T.type = M.type AND T.MASTERcode = M.MASTERcode
    AND T.SUBcode = M.SUBcode
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.  i have researched and tried various option like these  `SELECT trn.trnvno, trn.trnvrdt, master.customername . trn.trnamt, trn.trnnarr1
FROM trn LEFT JOIN master ON trn.trngsc = master.gsc
WHERE (((trn.trnaccd)=[master].[smstcode]))
GROUP BY ctrn.TRNACCD, ctrn.trnsubcd, ctrn.trnvno, ctrn.trnvrdt, ctrn.trnamt, ctrn.trnnarr1;`  but i am getting parial result.  Problem i feel is with master table which has mastercode and submastercode which both don't have unique value.  i don't have enough point to post screenshot, but very soon earn that too.. Thanks